# Linear Trend of NDVI time series

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, linear-regression, trend

I want to extract the linear trend of my NDVI time series. When I use the linear regression in Python using this code:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

data_orig = pd.read_csv('NDVI.csv')

N_values = data_orig['N'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
NDVI_values = data_orig['NDVI'].values

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(N_values, NDVI_values)

slope = model.coef_[0]
intercept = model.intercept_
print("Linear trend equation: NDVI = {:.4f} * N + {:.4f}".format(slope, intercept))
```

The output of this code is `Linear trend equation: NDVI = 0.0000 * N + 0.0485`.

I don't think this equation is correct because the vegetation in the time series is clearly increasing over time.

I also tried LOESS with this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

data_orig = pandas.read_csv('NDVI.csv')
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL
res = STL(data_orig['NDVI'], period=46, trend_jump=460).fit()
```

From this I got a good and significant upward trend. However, I want to know if it's ok to set the `trend_jump` to 460 (which is the number of my time series values).

This is my time series: [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Linear trend equation: NDVI = {:.4f} * N + {:.4f}".format(slope, intercept))
```

This code is rounding the slope to four decimal places before printing. Eyeballing [the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sshsn.png), it appears to go up by 0.015 over the course of 460 steps.

The slope this implies approximately [0.015 / 460 = 0.000032](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.015+%2F+460). Rounded to four decimal places, that's 0.0000.

Therefore, I think LinearRegression probably *is* detecting a slope - but one that is zero after rounding it.

I think this would probably work:

```
print("Linear trend equation: NDVI = {:.8f} * N + {:.4f}".format(slope, intercept))
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much. But I'm still wondering if it's ok to set the trend_jump to 460 in LOESS method. Do you have an idea?